# React-native-razorpay error codes and its description

Tags: react-native, error-code, razorpay

I want to show error popup message to the user according to error codes in the react-native-razorpay. Can anyone tell me the error codes with description

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out?
https://razorpay.com/docs/api/#error-codes
Razorpay official documentation suggests these error codes.